# How do I run my nuxt app on a different URL and port using pm2?

Tags: nuxt.js, pm2

I want to run my Nuxt app on a different URL and port using pm2 and the ecosystem.config.js.

I want it to run like the following package.json script:

```
"devhost": "nuxt --hostname 'my.url.domain' --port 8080"
```

This scipt allows me to run my nuxt app on my desired port and url. But if I follow the configuration given by the nuxt documentation [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-pm2), the app runs on `localhost:3000` and with that I cant run the app on a different machine, making it problematic.

Unfortunately, I have searched the net and can't seem to find a solution to my specific situation.

I tried changing the `script` option to `script: "npm"` and setting `args` like so: `args: "devhost"` but even this didn't work.

Running `pm2 logs` says `can't run command "nuxt-dev-host"` and, therefore, it didn't work.

I also tried to change `script` to `./node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` with the same `args` but it still didn't work.

**Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

The official homepage shows how to build with express.

According to the official website, make server.js and code like this.

```js
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require("nuxt");

const app = require("express")();
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3080;

// We instantiate Nuxt.js with the options
const config = require("./nuxt.config.js");
config.dev = !isProd;
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

// Render every route with Nuxt.js
app.use(nuxt.render);

// Build only in dev mode with hot-reloading
if (config.dev) {
  new Builder(nuxt).build().then(listen);
} else {
  listen();
}

function listen() {
  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port);
  console.log("Server listening on `localhost:" + port + "`.");
}
```

Then go to package.json and write the script.

```js
"start": "cross-env PORT=80 NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js"
```

The caveat here is that NODE_ENV is in deployment mode, so it is used as production, and the questioner is in development mode, so there is a difference.

The cross-env module must be installed.

Comment: I don't want to serve my nuxt app using express. I want it served in a static manner, the jumstack way. Anyway, even if this worked, I don't believe it is the correct way to do it. There must be a much more elegant way to configure pm2 without changing my website code. Like I did with the package.json script above for example. **Another big part is that I would love to achieve this using ecosystem.config.js**